# git - how can I clone local svn repository?

Tags: git, clone, git-svn

I am completely unable to find any explanation how I should specify location of existing svn repository.

In other words - what should be used as URL in

```
git svn clone URL
```

when svn repository is local?

Answer (score 68):

You should be able to succeed like this:

```
git svn clone file:///e/svn_repo_on_E_drive
```

Similar to svn checkout command:

```
svn co file:///e/svn_repo_on_E_drive
```

`file://` for folder on the current drive of the executing CMD prompt, `file:///d/some_folder` for `D:\some_folder`.

Note: The extra `/` and the removed colon `:` in the file link on Windows. `file://e:/svn_repo_on_E_drive` → `file:///e/svn_repo_on_E_drive`

##### `git svn clone` also works on remote svn repos

```
# for example
git svn clone https://your.hostname/path/here/svn/
```

- note: `git svn clone` gets **all** commits, as opposed to `svn checkout` only getting the most recent file set, and so the shell command can take a **long time** if the svn repo has lots of commits and/or files.

Comment: I was having a problem with this approach until I removed the colon (:) from drive on the file URL. Usually, in windows you see this file:///e:/svn_repo_on_E_drive , but for git you need to remove the ':' from the drive, leaving file:///e/svn_repo_on_E_drive

Comment: Thanks @kurast, i'll make the answer more obvious to remove it.

Comment: For me it does not work in any combination of /// and other things: 
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file://d/temp/xxxx': Local URL 'file://d/temp/xxxx' contains unsupported hostname at /
mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 144.

Comment: @flohack, based on the syntax, i assume you are using the command on Windows? Have you tried `file:///d/temp/xxxx`? What's the full command used when you get the error?

Comment: With 3 /// I get slightly different result:
$ git svn clone file:///d/temp/xxxx/
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/yyyy.lt/git/xxxx/.git/
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///d/temp/xxxx': Unable to open repository 'file:///d/temp/xxxx' at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 144.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am able to reproduce the same error you guys get. Which means, the behavior of Git has changed over time? Hmm.

Comment: I finally installed svn+ssh server only to do this import :)

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use svnserve to serve so you can use `svn://` over `file:///`. A great workaround!

Comment: Try to create a symbolic link of the repository in a different drive to the new location, then you do not need to mess with drive letters in your `file:///`.

Comment: Your reply saved my old repo which i was going to dump. Unable to find anywhere else:
file://e:/svn_repo_on_E_drive → file:///e/svn_repo_on_E_drive

Comment: Can not make it work. Got this error: ```Unable to open repository 'file:///d/projects/xxx' at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 310.``` I am using the git version of  ```version 2.34.0.windows.1```.

Comment: What finally worked for me in Linux on the command line was `file://localhost/absolute/path/to/svn`.

Answer (score 9):

For a local repository you use a `file://` URL, same as would be used for doing 
a checkout with the normal svn client.

If you're trying to copy the entire history, and using `git svn clone 
--stdlayout` just use the URL that you would use to checkout the trunk with svn 
minus the `/trunk` portion at the end.

Comment: So file:///X:/path/to/repos should work? Weird, as it fails with "Couldn't open a repository: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Unable to open repository"

Comment: `file://` URLs work for me. No idea about the drive specifier portion, I don't use windows.

Comment: From your last comment I suppose you're using Windows.
Try to remove the third "/".
Maybe it doesn't work because there's a bug: https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1402

Comment: You need to remove the colon ( : ) from the drive letter. So instead of file:///X:/path/to/repos you need to use file:///X/path/to/repos