# git - how can I clone a subfolder of a local svn repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control

My question is probably related to [git - how can I clone local svn repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374353/git-how-can-i-clone-local-svn-repository) but I cannot quite achieve what I want to.

We have an old local SVN repository. It looks like a single repository, but there are multiple different projects under this repository, like:

```
project1/
    project1_subproject1/
    project1_subproject2/
    project1_subproject3/
project2/
    project2_subproject1/
    project2_subproject2/
    project2_subproject3/
...
```

I am trying to `git svn clone` just one of the sub-projects, not the entire repository, but I am really not sure how to do that.

The main repository is under: `/home/user/projects/subversion/`

I tried `git svn clone file:///home/user/projects/subversion/project2/project2_subproject1` but obviously that fails.

I also tried `git svn clone --trunk=project2/project2_subproject1 file:///home/user/projects/subversion/`, but that also fails.

Both tries result in `W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found:`

Note: I have managed to clone the entire subversion repository into one single git repository using `git svn clone file:///home/user/projects/subversion/`, but that's not what I want.

Any help please?

Comment: What if instead of using this path you use the http path? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962641/1701296

Comment: What's the OS you are using?

Comment: Hi I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The commands `git svn clone file:///home/user/projects/subversion/project2/project2_subproject1` can also works for linux. Please make sure the `project2` folder is located in the **root of svn repo** (not under `trunk/` or `branches/` etc). And what if you add the option `--no-metadata` in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clone the whole svn repository, replicate and clean up**

Possibly the easiest way is to:

- clone the full SVN repository
- copy the cloned repository N times, where N is the number of independent projects
- clean up each individual git repository, such that only one project remains

For the last step, see [Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)